# JavaScript keep tab on page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I have tabbed content that looks like this:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

And JavaScript for the tabs that looks like this:

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

I'm using the code from W3 schools. When the page is reloaded I want the tab that I am on to stay not for it to reload to the default tab.
EDIT: For clarification, I want the last tab I clicked to load when I refresh the page.

Comment: You want to go to the default tab after reload? or do you want to go to the tab you clicked the last time?

Comment: Tab I clicked last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some persistent storage method to achieve this: cookies or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You have to save the name of a clicked tab inside your `openCity` function and read it near your click on `id="defaultOpen"`. If no value has been read from cookie or localStorage, perform your default click.

I recommend PPK's [cookie functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using hashtags in the url.

You should change your buttont to `<a>`
like so:

```
   <a class="tablinks" href="#london" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a>
```

Then on document ready check for hashtag and select the desired tab:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.hash == ""){
      openCity(event, 'London')
    } else if( window.location.hash == "#paris"{
      openCity(event, 'Paris')
    }
});
```

etc